# A weird bug about shrinkResources in Android

Tags: java, android, shrinkresources

shrinkResources is configed as true in `build.gradle`.

Then I found this weird bug:

In a java file of my app, there is one line like this:

`String unit = String.format("%%s %s", getResources().getString(R.string.XXXX));`

Note that there is a space in `%%s %s`

if I add this space, some of my PNGs will be marked as unused resource by ShrinkResources, and won't be packaged into the apk file.

But if I omit the space, everything is fine.

For me it's unbelievable.It's gonna drive me crazy...Any idea about this?

update:

trying to make my question more clear:

if my java code is

`String unit = String.format("%%s %s", getResources().getString(R.string.XXXX));`

Then part of the outputs is(in fact I found it in `resources.txt`):

`Skipped unused resource res/drawable-xxhdpi-v4/head02.9.png: 822 bytes (replaced with small dummy file of size 77 bytes)
Skipped unused resource res/drawable-xxhdpi-v4/appointment_normal.png: 1827 bytes (replaced with small dummy file of size 67 bytes)
Skipped unused resource res/drawable-xxhdpi-v4/cg_normal.png: 1850 bytes (replaced with small dummy file of size 67 bytes)
Skipped unused resource res/drawable-xxhdpi-v4/pre_normal.png: 1822 bytes (replaced with small dummy file of size 67 bytes)
Skipped unused resource res/drawable-xxhdpi-v4/doctor_normal.png: 1963 bytes (replaced with small dummy file of size 67 bytes)
Skipped unused resource res/drawable-xxhdpi-v4/infor_normal.png: 1605 bytes (replaced with small dummy file of size 67 bytes)
Skipped unused resource res/drawable-xxhdpi-v4/btn_check.png: 716 bytes (replaced with small dummy file of size 67 bytes)
Skipped unused resource res/drawable-xxhdpi-v4/btn_check.png: 898 bytes (replaced with small dummy file of size 67 bytes)
Skipped unused resource res/drawable-xxhdpi-v4/navigation_arrow_left_normal.png: 184 bytes (replaced with small dummy file of size 67 bytes)
Skipped unused resource res/drawable-xxhdpi-v4/dameon_killed.png: 913 bytes (replaced with small dummy file of size 67 bytes)`

The pngs that skipped will not be displayed.

if my java code is

`String unit = String.format("%%s%s", getResources().getString(R.string.XXXX));`

no outputs like I posted above, and everything is fine.

Comment: may you provide some print of Android Studio, your questions is quite unclear

Comment: I have updated some outputs...could you help me?